# Restangular getList() returns empty array

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

My factory that uses Restangular getList() method returns empty array despite getting records from database in spring controller which handles backend side of operation. I don't know if the cause of this problem is in java or angular side of application. Why is this happening?

FlightController.java

```
package regularmike.airline.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import regularmike.airline.entity.Flight;
import regularmike.airline.service.FlightService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/flight")
public class FlightController {

    @Autowired
    FlightService flightService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getFlights", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public List<Flight> getAllFlights() {
        List<Flight> allFlights = flightService.getAllFlights();    

        return allFlights;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public Flight getSeats(@PathVariable long id) {
        Flight result = flightService.getByFlightid(id);

        return result;
    }

}
```

FlightFactory.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict'

    angular.module('airline').factory('FlightFactory', FlightFactory);

    function FlightFactory(Restangular) {
        function getAllFlights() {
            return Restangular.all('flight/getFlights').getList();
        }
        return {
            getAllFlights: getAllFlights
        };  
    }
})();
```

DashboardController.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict'

    angular.module('airline').controller('DashboardController', ['FlightFactory', DashboardController]);

    function DashboardController(FlightFactory) {
        var dashCtrl = this;

        FlightFactory
        .getAllFlights()
        .then(getFlights)

        function getFlights(response)
        {
            dashCtrl.flights = response;
            console.log(dashCtrl.flights);
        }
    }

})();
```

config.js

```
(function() {
    angular.module('airline').config(
            [ 'RestangularProvider', restangularConfig ]);

    function restangularConfig(RestangularProvider) {
        RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/');

        RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders(
                {"Accept": 'application/json'},
        {"Content-Type": "application/json+hal"});

        RestangularProvider.setResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what) {
            var resp;
            if (operation === 'get') {
                if (_.has(data, '_embedded')) {
                    resp = data._embedded;
                } else {
                    resp = data;
                }
                if (_.has(data, '_links')) {
                    resp._links = data._links;
                }
                return resp;
            }
            if (operation === 'getList') {
                if (_.has(data, '_embedded')) {
                    resp = data._embedded[what];
                } else {
                    resp = [];
                }
                if (_.has(data, '_links')) {
                    resp._links = data._links;
                }
                return resp;
            }
            return data;
        });

        RestangularProvider.setRequestInterceptor(function (element, operation, route, url) {
            if (operation === 'put' || operation === 'post') {
                if (angular.isDefined(element._links)) {
                    element._links.self.href = element._links.self.href.split('{?projection}')[0];
                }
                return element;
            }
        });

        RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
            selfLink: '_links.self.href'
        });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the method that returning the list should be bound to the web respond body, which is in your case JSON representation (Notice that *`@ResponseBody`*).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFlights", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public  @ResponseBody List<Flight> getAllFlights() {
        List<Flight> allFlights = flightService.getAllFlights();    
        return allFlights;   
    }
```

Also, to make it work, don't forget to set up json provider to the Spring side.

```
<!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
<!--jackson-core-asl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```